# Python Struct.Unpack in C++ (Bitshift?)

Tags: python, c++, ros

```
data = struct.unpack('!10H'%length, buf[:20])
```

Now assuming C++ where buf is a std::string.
Could I just write:

```
uint8_t f1 = (buf[0] << 8) | buf[1];
uint8_t f2 = (buf[2] << 8) | buf[3];
```

?
I have to translate a python ROS-IMU driver to ROS-C++ and have to deal with a lot of struct unpacks. I read about different ways to translate the code, some said declaring a corresponding struct and execute memcpy or reinterprete_cast, others said to use bitshift. That's what I got compiling so far. Would this do what I want it to do? Or how do I cast a std::string or uint8_t array to the corresponding values?

And what does the percent sign (%) before dB mean in this unpack? In the python manual this parameter is not listed under Format Parameters.

```
data = struct.unpack('!%dB'%length, buf[:-1])
```

Comment: I think it's just `'%d'` for decimal. The B is just added to the end of the string.

Comment: this part: `uint8_t f1 = (buf[0] << 8)` is useless. The destination data type is 8 bit, you shift away all bits.

Comment: `'!%dB'%length` becomes `'!??B'` where `??` is `str(length)`. It's just dynamically defining the number of `unsigned char`s in the format string based on the numeric value of `length`.

Comment: The `'!10H'%length` part makes no sense since there's no `%` in the `'!10H'` part, and should result in a `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`.

Comment: Okay this was just a sample. In the original code there was also a % in the formatting parameter. Forgott to include that

Comment: @Wimmel What would I have to do then? Thanks

Comment: And how would I solve that in C++? I can't write code for every possible data-type?!

Comment: @SebastianMüller This question assumes knowledge of both python and c++. That reduces the audience. My python knowledge is too limited to understand what you are trying to do. But I also doubt if it really possible to convert a python statement 1:1 into c++. There are too many differences. To answer the c++ part, I think it is required to know the input (type) and output. And possibly why you want to do that, there might be a better way in c++ to solve your problem.